# Links List dropdown menu hyperlinks

Tags: sharepoint-designer, hyperlink, dropdown

SP2007
Using a Links List, I want to:

1. Convert to DVWP
2. Change layout to dropdown
3. Enable list items to direct/redirect user to url of the selected list item

Numbers 1 and 2 are cake. Been there, done that.

Number 3 however is not. When converting the DVWP to a dropdown layout, the links (urls) lose the url. They no longer work. Nothing redirects the user.

So now I have this:

```
<xsl:template name="dvt_1">
<xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">Drpdwn</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" />
<select name="ID" size="1">
<option selected="true" value="0">Choose One...</option>
<xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
    <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows" />
</xsl:call-template>
</select>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
        <xsl:param name="Rows" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview" />
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
    <option>
    <a href="{substring-before(@URL, ', ')}">
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@URL, ', ')" />
   </a>
    </option>
</xsl:template>
```

I have tried several things but nothing seems to work. And since I don't know much about code, I could have been real close to getting it done, just wasn't sure what to look for or change.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind an event to the selection of the item to navigate to the url.

Matt ([@ionline247](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/3136/ionline247)) has an example here, http://mattbramer.blogspot.com/2010/10/sharepoint-integrate-aspnet-controls_28.html

Comment: Yeah. Don't know how to do that. I need to populate the ddl with user friendly text, but have SP use the actual URL to do the redirect. I don't know how to make that happen.

Comment: The above series of articles explains that.

Answer (score 0):

Mike - If the number of list items you are linking to is small (i.e. around 10) and will remain fairly static, this post may help you out:  https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2014/07/06/use-the-html-form-web-part-to-create-a-drop-down-of-links/